# Navigation sub-menu z-index

Tags: css, z-index

The website is: http://webdizajntest.com/egida/

I have a problem with positioning sub menu that appears on hover, behind main navigation ul element.

I want that div with class ***sub-menu*** to appear behind (below) ul list with id **sticky_menu**

Does anyone have a clue what approach should I use?

Here is the code:

```
<div class='sticky_menu sticky_menu_style1 sticky_menu_980px sticky_menu_top '>
    <ul id="sticky_menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-43"> 
            <a href="#">Kursevi jezika za odrasle<span>  </span></a>
            <div class="sub-menu clearfix   ">
                <div id="menu-item-64" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-64">
                     <h6>Kategorija 2<span>  </span></h6>
                </div>
                <div id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-63">
                     <h6>Kategorija 3<span>  </span></h6>
                </div>
                <div id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-54">
                     <h6>Kategorija 4<span>  </span></h6>
                </div>
                <div id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-70">
                     <h6>Kategorija 5<span>  </span></h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot of how it should look like when it goes behind: http://oi42.tinypic.com/2akk1he.jpg

Thank you!

Comment: Please show some of your code or create a jsfiddle so we know where you're at.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try  :

```
#sticky_menu li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

in webdizajntest.com/egida/wp-content/plugins/sticky_menu/sprites/css/sticky_menu.css?ver=1.0

line 90 to be exact

Comment: Not working, i think that a element is not relevant, div class sub-menu is the issue

Comment: the main li is getting displaced into second line. If you rectify that, the drop menu will align just fine. Ive edited this via firebug and its looking good.. Hmm..

Comment: It still isn't behind ul! See the screenshot o fwhat i want to achieve: http://oi42.tinypic.com/2akk1he.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Check your sticky_menu.css line number 69 and change the 'top' value

```
.sticky_menu_top #sticky_menu div.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 68px; // this value of 68px is looking good, you can change it as you see it fit
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, but no. :) I want it to appear BEHIND ul with id sticky_menu

Comment: Then you'll have to change the markup. You can not take a child element behind its parent. your .submenu  and ul#stick_menu should be at same level and not nested.